# Visualizing the hinge loss and 0-1 loss

Tags: loss-functions, hinge-loss

I have seen the plot below in many textbooks before. What do the **X axis** and the **Y axis** represent exactly? What does it mean for the Hinge loss to "touch" the 0-1 loss on the (x,y) pair (0,1)?

If helpful, the source of this picture is from the entry on [Hinge Loss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hinge_loss) on Wikipedia.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The x-axis is the score output from a classifier, often interpreted as the estimated/predicted log-odds. The y-axis is the loss for a single datapoint with true label $y = 1$.

In notation, if we denote the score output from the classifier as $\hat s$, the plots are the graphs of the functions:

$$ f(\hat s) = \text{Zero-One-Loss}(\hat s, 1) $$
$$ f(\hat s) = \text{Hinge-Loss}(\hat s, 1) $$